# Integers and Floats mixed without separators

Tags: regex, sed

So whether I solve this problem with regex, a sed script or a spreadsheet function I am not sure but, at this point I am not quite sure how to attack this issue.

I have a field that represents 3 distinct fields and I need to either divide them up or accurately select each discreet section. My problem is that each value can be either an integer or a float in any order. eg:

[int]**[int]**[int] -->4**3**2

[int]**[float]**[int] -->4**0.5**2

[float]**[int]**[float] -->1.5**8**3.5

I was thinking about writing multiple regex statements until I cover all possible cases but, I was wondering if there is some way to call . a separator and split anything without a separator.

Comment: How do you divide for example 123.456?

Comment: what if you get `3456` ? there's 3 `int`s but which ones? you would have to provide one more criterion to have a chance to succeed (for instance: maximum value)

Comment: To summarize the above two comments - this is possible to do unambiguously if and only if an "int" is a single digit and a "float" is two digits separated by a decimal point. Things like "1." or ".2" will cause problems as much as the other given examples - your 40.52 case could be (4, 0.5, 2) or (40, .5, 2) or (4, 0., 52). Even in that restrictive case, though, I doubt a forest of regular expressions is the best way to solve it...

Comment: @twalberg In all cases an int is a single digit [0-9] and the floats are always in the form \d.\d with the leading digit always present and they never excede one place on either side of the decimal. What would the best tool be to solve this?

Comment: @ChrisRichardson I would think a simple loop over each character with a simple look-ahead - if it's not followed by a decimal point, it's an int, and you process that one character. If it is followed by a decimal point, you take three characters and process them as a float. `python` comes to mind as a reasonable language to use, but `perl` or `C` or many others would all be suitably capable. Even `lex`/`flex` would work.

Comment: What result do you expect? sed is a command line tool, do you want to write the numbers to stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is not too difficult with the restrictions you gave in the comment (ints from 0 to 9 and floats from 0.0 to 9.9):

```
(\d\.\d|\d)(\d\.\d|\d)(\d\.\d|\d)
```

Why this works: regex are greedy and the options are checked from left to right (if the number isn't a float then it has to be an int) and you have the numbers in groups 1 to 3.

https://regex101.com/r/3z7TL3/1

Comment: That would allow three floats as well, which is not a valid pattern here

Comment: "each value can be either an integer or a float in any order" and I assume that the string is always valid, othewise you can add anchors `^...$`.

Comment: I will mark this correct it handles exactly what I asked for. unfortunately around line 100K in the file I am working I found new cases. I was hoping to do this quick and dirty but, I will have to write a script to parse the separate cases.